# Rcpp: cannot access module class inside R code of the same package

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

Let's say I want to build a very simple package in R that wraps c++ code.
My test project would be called *bananas*.

Let's say I have a folder called "**bananas**", where inside I have two other folders one called **c++** and one called **R**.

Inside the **c++** folder I have folder called **include** that contains the  **bananas.hpp** header file (with the class definition):

```
#ifndef BANANAS_H
#define BANANAS_H

class Bananas
{
  public:
  void add_banana();
  int get_bananas();

  protected:
  int number_of_bananas;
};

#endif
```

Outside **include**  there is the **bananas.cpp** file that **implements** the methods of **bananas.hpp**:

```
#include "include/bananas.hpp"
using namespace std;

void Bananas::add_banana(){
    // Return False if edge already existed
    number_of_bananas ++;
}

int Bananas::get_bananas(){
    return number_of_bananas;
}
```

now in my **R** folder I have a the **wrapper.cpp** file that uses Rcpp library to export c++ classes inside R as a module:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include "include/bananas.hpp"

using namespace Rcpp;

RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS(Bananas)

RCPP_MODULE(Bananas_cpp){

  class_<Bananas>("BananasCPP")
  .default_constructor()
  .method("add_banana", &Bananas::add_banana)
  .method("get_bananas", &Bananas::get_bananas)
  ;
}
```

Note that right now `#include "include/bananas.hpp"` does not mean anything, but in the future this file will be added inside source.
Finally I have my main concern which a R wrapper of this class under:

```
require(R6)
library(Rcpp)

# For exposing the error
print(ls(all.names = TRUE))

# Load Module
bcpp <- Module("Bananas_cpp", PACKAGE="RBananasC", mustStart = TRUE)$BananasCPP

Bananas <- R6Class("Bananas", list(
   bn = new(bcpp),
   print_bananas = function() {print(self$bn$get_bananas())},
   banana_tree = function(d) {
     for(row in 1:d){
        self$bn$add_banana()
     }
   }
 ))
```

Now when running the **setup.R** file in my main directory which looks as follows:

```
require(Rcpp)

# Make a base package
unlink("RBananasC", recursive=TRUE)
Rcpp.package.skeleton(name = "RBananasC", list = character(), 
                      path = ".", force = FALSE, 
                      cpp_files = c("bananas/R/wrapper.cpp", "bananas/c++/bananas.cpp", "bananas/c++/include/bananas.hpp"))
dir.create("RBananasC/src/include")
file.rename("RBananasC/src/bananas.hpp", "RBananasC/src/include/bananas.hpp")
install.packages("RBananasC", repos=NULL, type="source")

# See that Bananas_cpp works
library(RBananasC) #Without this line it doesn't work

print(Module("Bananas_cpp", PACKAGE="RBananasC", mustStart = TRUE)$BananasCPP)
bcpp <- Module("Bananas_cpp", PACKAGE="RBananasC", mustStart = TRUE)$BananasCPP
ban <- new(bcpp)
ban$add_banana()
print(ban$get_bananas())

# Make the desired package
unlink("RBananas", recursive=TRUE)
Rcpp.package.skeleton(name = "RBananas", list = character(), 
                      path = ".", force = FALSE, 
                      code_files = c("bananas/R/bananas.R"), cpp_files = c("bananas/R/wrapper.cpp", "bananas/c++/bananas.cpp", "bananas/c++/include/bananas.hpp"))
dir.create("RBananas/src/include")
file.rename("RBananas/src/bananas.hpp", "RBananas/src/include/bananas.hpp")
install.packages("RBananas", repos=NULL, type="source")
```

I have a very strange behaviour inside my **bananas.R** file, that has to do with the fact that **Bananas_cpp** module of my package is not visible and so I cannot access the class **BananasCPP** upon installation.
On the other hand if I ignore the file **bananas.R** I can import the **BananasCPP** from the module **Bananas_cpp** of the package **RBananasC**, I created using **Rcpp.package.skeleton**.

To sum up the total file structure looks like:

```
.
├── bananas
│   ├── c++
│   │   ├── bananas.cpp
│   │   └── include
│   │       └── bananas.hpp
│   └── R
│       ├── bananas.R
│       └── wrapper.cpp
└── setup.R
```

And to demonstrate what is my problem you just run the **setup.R**.

I followed a standard [tutorial](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-modules.pdf), but I couldn't find any information of how I can load my **BananasCPP** class from the **Bananas_cpp** module inside my **Bananas.R** wrap function **Bananas**, while searching for days in the internet. This file does not appear in the namespace of the environment active inside the package, so I think this what should be tackled: "which commands I should add and where to expose my **Bananas_cpp** module inside the current namespace of the package".

Of course this is a reproducible that I made from a real problem I had.
Thanks a lot for your support!

Comment: This is too long for me to study in detail but the top-level question is: why are you reinventing package layout when existing packages with modules exist and you could just copy that structure?

Comment: Dirk is right. You should make a package. For a course, I've made a quick tuto to make a package (including Rcpp and some includes in *inst/*) [here](https://privefl.github.io/advr38book/packages.html).

Comment: The top level question is: "'which' commands should I add and 'where', in order expose an Rcpp module containing a class inside the current namespace of the package, for the execution of a R file of the same package upon installation". My problem is that the R file cannot see the Rcpp module that is produced and compiled successfully inside the package, when installed. I used the Rcpp skeleton in order to demonstrate this error with the basic package Rcpp skeleton (when everything is declared appropriately), which should work with such a basic example (except if I forgot to declare something).

Comment: The skeleton generator used to have a 'create with Modules' mode, but we took that out.  For a minimal package, look at one [included with our unit tests](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/tree/master/inst/unitTests/testRcppModule); for (larger) real life ones my RcppRedis and RcppCNPy and RcppAnnoy packages may suit (but they may also distract you as they need more stuff).  I'd start with the minimal one.

Comment: I have followed this basic example but it doesn't say anything about **classes**. Propably what I want is the similar command for loading a **class** instead of a [function](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/inst/unitTests/testRcppModule/R/rcpp_hello_world.R).